# How do I create a textfile in java?

Tags: java, text-files

So here's the rundown. I have an assignment I have to complete that involves creating a textile (consisting of several lines, each with six numbers). and then reading the numbers from that textfiles to use as input for our program. To my great shame, I was never taught about textfiles in my java class, and have no idea how to make them. I've done my googling to figure it out for myself, but I'm not sure if what i'm finding is what I'm looking for. Can anyone offer me assistance?

Comment: Show us what you have tried - we need a [mcve] before we can help you; you need to up your Google-fu too - "create a textfile in java" gives me a highlighted snippet of the code!

Comment: Already asked question, maybe it can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java